# sort listview by existence in another arraylist

Tags: java, android, sorting, listview, arraylist

In an android program I am creating, each user will have an arraylist preference, the code i'm using will just make the question needlessly complex, but say I have a list of pets I'm displaying in a listview.  Every page will have the entire list of pets, say

```
ArrayList<Pet> allPetsList = {"dogs", "cats", "parrots", "mice", "hamsters", "guinea pigs"}
```

The user will want to see all of the pets info, but will want to see the kind of pet they have first, so there's another array list, pets I have, which say has `ArrayList<Pet> myPets {"cats", "mice"}`.  How can I sort the list of all pets so it displays cats and mice first, then displays the rest?

I was going to use

```
allPetsList.sort(myPetsList, new Comparator<Item>() {
public int compare(Item left, Item right) {
    if (myPetsList.contains(left)) {
return 1;
}
else {
return 0;}
     }
});`
```

but it would appear the ArrayList.sort function is deprecated, and I'm not sure if this would work anyway.  How can it be done?  I don't think it'll matter much but the Pet object contains the name string and two ints, so the variable would have to be `.getName()`.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give the expected for the Lists input ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove the all the elements of first List from the second list, then create a `LinkedList`(to keep the order) to combine the rest together :

```
List<Pets> resultList = new LinkedList<>();
List<Pets> firstList  =  {"cats", "mice"};
List<Pets> secondList = {"dogs", "cats", "parrots", "mice", "hamsters", "guinea pigs"};

secondList.removeAll(firstList);//{"dogs", "parrots", "hamsters", "guinea pigs"}

resultList.addAll(firstList);//{"cats", "mice"}
resultList.addAll(secondList);//{"cats", "mice", "dogs", "parrots", "hamsters", "guinea pigs"}
```

---

**Edit**

A coring to your comment you can solve your problem following this steps :

- User `hashCode()` and `equals(..)` method in your class Object like this :

...

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 53 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.name);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Pet other = (Pet) obj;
    if (!Objects.equals(this.name, other.name)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

...

- Then find all the elements from the principal list
- remove them
- and then add them in the top

Here is a way using Java 8 :

```
List<Pet> namesList = new LinkedList<>(
        Arrays.asList(
                new Pet("cats", 0, 0),
                new Pet("mice", 0, 0)
        )
);

List<Pet> petsList = new LinkedList<>(
        Arrays.asList(
                new Pet("dogs", 16, 18),
                new Pet("cats", 36, 99),
                new Pet("parrots", 85, 25),
                new Pet("mice", 70, 28),
                new Pet("hamsters", 12, 41),
                new Pet("guinea pigs", 75, 95)
        )
);

List<Pet> newList = petsList.stream()
        .filter(t -> namesList.contains(t))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());//find the necessary objects

petsList.removeAll(newList);//remove them from the principal list
petsList.addAll(0, newList);//add the result on the top
```

---

#### Check the demo code

Comment: I should have mentioned this before but there is an issue in that the secondList has the whole pet object I need to retrieve, while firstList either just has strings corresponding to the pets name, or Pet objects with only a name. Is there a way to alter your code so that I'm still getting the objects from secondList but just changing the order?

Comment: @PaxanaNonGrata if i can understand there are a List of all pets, and a list of name of pets that should be in the start of your list, this second list is a list of String, can you confirm?

Comment: Yes that's correct, however the list of pets that should be at the start only exists at the default constructor, so the Dog object in that would actually be Pet("Dog", 0, 0) , however the dog object in the larger list contains more valuable information like Pet("Dog", 16, 9) and that dog object is the one I need to display, I can't actually use them interchangeably

Comment: @PaxanaNonGrata check my edit hope this is what you need :)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the link. Hope you will find your solution on the example.

https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Mainly you have to add compareTo method to your **Pet** class and some little operations. Sorry for giving you the gist.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tested code below, hope you find it helpful:

```
        List<Pet> listOfAllPets = new ArrayList<Pet>();
        listOfAllPets.add(new Pet("dogs"));
        listOfAllPets.add(new Pet("cats"));
        listOfAllPets.add(new Pet("parrots"));
        listOfAllPets.add(new Pet("mice"));
        listOfAllPets.add(new Pet("hamsters"));

        List<Pet> listOfMyPets = new ArrayList<Pet>();
        listOfMyPets.add(new Pet("mice"));
        listOfMyPets.add(new Pet("cats"));

       //Fill the Map with All Pets
        final HashMap<String, Integer> allPetsMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfAllPets.size(); i++) {
            allPetsMap.put(listOfAllPets.get(i).Name, i);
        }

        //sort AllPets
        Collections.sort(listOfAllPets);

        //sort MyPets using Map of AllPets
        Collections.sort(listOfMyPets, new Comparator<Pet>() {
            public int compare(Pet obj1, Pet obj2) {
                return allPetsMap.get(obj1.getName()) - allPetsMap.get(obj2.getName());
            }
        });

        //this is just to print Results:[cats, mice, cats, dogs, hamsters, mice, parrots]

        List<Pet> sortedPets = new ArrayList<Pet>(listOfMyPets);

        sortedPets.addAll(listOfAllPets.removeAll(listOfMyPets)? listOfMyPets :listOfAllPets);

        System.out.println(sortedPets.stream().map(i -> i.getName()).collect( toList() ) );
```